# MS Access Validation - All the values in Column 2 should be the same according the distinct values in Column 1

Tags: sql, validation, ms-access

I can better explain with an example:

I need to verify a table whether the distinct values from 'ProdID' column (say 713141535) has the same set of values in 'AccountNo' column (say 2), i.e., Prodid with '713141535' has the same AccountNo which is '2','2','2'. (Refer image from below link)

But the prodid '855325150' has different AccountNo which is 5,4,5. All the account numbers are not the same according to ProdID, so the validation is failed.

Could you please help me to write a query to  validate this type of scenario using MS Access.

Note: I get new tables for each release, so I am unaware of the values in table as it differs every time.

Thanks

Basha

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/ms-access-validation-all-the-values-in-column-2/10d957ef-94f7-48ff-b708-277dbb01d077?tm=1405338095580

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DISTINCT` to find the mismatches between `ProdID` and `AccountNo` and use that recordset as your subquery.

```
SELECT Sub.ProdID, Count(Sub.ProdID) AS CountOfProdID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ProdID, AccountNo
FROM Prod
)  AS Sub
GROUP BY Sub.ProdID
HAVING Count(Sub.ProdID) > 1
```

Note: I used `Prod` as my table name. `Sub` is the alias given to the subquery.

This query will return the `ProdID` that has mismatches in `AccountNo`

Comment: @Basha Great! If you feel I have adequately answered your question feel free to mark my post as the 'answer' but clicking the grey check mark just under the up and down arrows to the left of my answer. This helps other users who may need the same solution identify what works vs what didn't. Here is a guide of the site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour